# How to convert JSON response to array of angular objects within service?

Tags: angular

EDIT: no need to answer, the problem was elsewhere. I apologize :(

I need getHeroes() to return an array of 'Hero'. It was working with the tutorial's in-memory data, but fails when I use my django rest API.

*hero.ts*

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

*hero.service.ts*

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
      return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response['heroes']),
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

*JSON response from API*

```
{
  "heroes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "hero1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "hero2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what were you expecting and what you actually got?

Comment: Yes, it would be good if you could post the output of what you got (if any). As well as making your question more so complete by stating what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry. My while I could see the XHR response sent by my django API, there was CORS problem. I did not have to change my code. Just had to allow CORS in django. Sorry to take up your time. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use within your component `subscribe`:

```
import { Hero } from "./heroComponent";

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero;

  constructor(private serv: YourService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serv.getHeroes().subscribe(serv => {
        this.heroes = serv
        console.log(this.heroes);
    });
  }

}
```

Of course, change some stuff to make it fit your code. It should map your JSON to to the Object.

**See if any of these help as well:**

This might be *more* to what you are asking: https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/

Others

[Map Json to object in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688512/map-json-to-object-in-angular)

https://coursetro.com/posts/code/171/Angular-7-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-7-by-Example
(scroll down to the HTTP service part of it)

Answer (score 0):

There's two options for this (leaving out error handling for brevity here):

**Option 1:** Treat the result as an `any` and cast the `heroes` property to an `Hero[]`

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
        map(res => res.heroes as Hero[])
    );
}
```

**Option 2 (preferable):** Create a model (e.g. `HeroResult`) that represents what your server actually returns to have full type safety

```
export class HeroResult {
    heroes: Hero[];
}

getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<HeroResult>(this.heroesUrl).pipe(
        map(res => res.heroes)
    );
}
```